# QuickSight Data Upload Issue using S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

I'm facing issue while uploading data to QuickSight using S3 bucket. It duplicates the rows and the result is double of the actual figure.

I tried to remove every column and only have one but still its duplicating it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I didn't create the manifest.json file correctly. By specifying the same file in both "URIs":and "URIPrefixes":.

You only need to choose one of those ways for specifying where the file is in S3 otherwise it will load the same file multiple times.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-manifest-file-format.html

Hope this helps!